# How can you access different positions of a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have the following Prolog program:

```
father(person1,person2).
mother(person3,person2).

 say_hi(X) :- father(X,person1) , write('Hello1').
 say_hi(X) :- father(X,person2) , write('Hello2').
```

I want to have a list of different sentences: the program should return  different sentences each time that you call say_hi

So , the expected output of the program should be:

```
 ?- say_hi(person1)
 Hello1
 ?- say_hi(person1)
 Hello3
 ?- say_hi(person4)
 Hello4
```

The different elements of the list should be written in a random way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just once each list' element, here is a possible definition (in SWI-Prolog), that returns elements on backtracking:

```
get_random([E], E) :- !.
get_random(L, E) :-
    length(L, C),
    R is random(C),
    length(Skip, R),
    append(Skip, [X|Tail], L),
    ( E = X
    ; append(Skip, Tail, Rest),
      get_random(Rest, E) ).
```

test:

```
?- get_random([a,b,c,d,e,f],X).
X = e ;
X = f ;
X = d ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = a.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Persons = [person1, person2, person3, person4],
length(Persons, N),
I is random(N),
nth0(I, Persons, P).
```

will unify `P` with a random element from the list `Persons` (in SWI-Prolog).

Answer (score 1):

You can make ir with `maybe` [http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maybe%2f1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maybe/1)
But I couldn't manage it to work.
So I've made my own maybe predicate:

```
maybe(P):-
    random(N),
    N<P.

maybe :- maybe(0.5).
```

I couldn't understand your initial code, so I've changed it a little.

```
say_hi :- maybe, write('Hello1').
say_hi :- write('Hello2').


?- say_hi.
Hello2
true.

?- say_hi.
Hello1
true .

?- say_hi.
Hello2
true.
```